# Getting a error numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

1. Im finding an illlogical error 
        'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' when i run the code of groupby  in  python The command is

   `df = df.groupby(df.columns[1]).sum().reset_index()`

Any help please go ahead

Comment: Your code works for a simple example I just tried using pandas `0.13.1` can you post a minimal code that reproduces your issue

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, and so I can find this on google.

Also: Python 2.7.6, Pandas 0.13.1.

The problem looks to be an empty dataframe. Pandas guys, if you're listening, you might do some input checking in the DataFrame.reset_index() method.

```
Bens-MacBook-Pro:RightAnalytics bdundee$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb  5 2014, 15:46:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df.reset_index()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2472, in reset_index
    new_obj.insert(0, name, values)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1965, in insert
    loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2918, in insert
    self._add_new_block(item, value, loc=loc)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3042, in _add_new_block
    self.blocks.append(new_block)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
>>>
```

Comment: This bug appears to have been fixed recently -- I can't reproduce it on pandas 0.14.1.